# "Dropped & Replaced" tx - what should I do?

Tags: gas, failed-transaction, usdt

I requested a USDT withdrawal from Bilaxy exchange to my Binance USDT (ERC20) account.

However, on etherscan, the transaction shows as "**Dropped & Replaced**".

Do you guys think I shhould I contact Bilaxy and ask them to resend it?

The Ethereum seems to be really slow and expensive at the moment??!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Dropped & Replaced" means the transaction has been replaced by a new one and the new one has been validated by the network (more info here : https://info.etherscan.com/transaction-dropped-replaced/).

Ethereum is effectively currently overloaded and the average gas price is very high (see here : https://ethgasstation.info/). My guess is that Bilaxy resent the transaction with a higher gas cost in order to match the current average price accepted by the miners.

Comment: Bilaxy fixed it for me and returned the USDT funds after checking the transaction. They were very responsive on the support chat and very helpful in finding out what the problem was and fixing it as soon as reasonably possible. Yes, the Ethereum network was extremely congested the last few days. Not the fault of exchanges - Ethereum is just too popular!

Comment: The link to etherscan you sent is broken (404).